# Better way to pass object by value to a method - C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, pass-by-reference

By default, objects are passed by reference to methods. I know a way to make a clone of the object and pass it to the method like a deep copy.

Here's one implementation for above approach (serialize it and  deserialize to a new object):

```
private static APIRateLimit DeepCopy(APIRateLimit source)
{
    var DeserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIRateLimit>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source), DeserializeSettings);
}
```

But, Is it the only way to do this? Is there any better approach for a scenario like this?

**Note:** I'm specific about the objects which contain primitives only without any readonly/constant modifiers.

Object is like this:

```
public class APIRateLimit
{
    public int MaxAllowed { get; set; }
    public int APICallDurationInSec { get; set; }
    public string APIRateLimitInfo { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionType   { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "By default, objects are passed by reference to methods." No, references are passed by value. See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html As for "how to make a deep copy" that entirely depends on what you're copying. Sometimes it's unnecessary (e.g. if it's an immutable type), sometimes it's easy (if the type provides something to do it for you) and sometimes it's effectively impossible (how do you deep copy a network socket?)

Comment: @JonSkeet That's good to know Skeet but, in my case object will have only primitives.

Comment: Okay, so that should be in the question - along with all other relevant information, such as whether all of the state is accessible via trivial read/write properties.

Comment: @JonSkeet Noted. I should've mentioned it before.

Comment: You still haven't explained whether everything is available via properties... or what constructors are available. Samples would make it much easier to help you here.

Comment: @JonSkeet updated the question with the proper example.

Comment: What about `struct` or `AutoMapper`?

Comment: @Zaggo0 Your suggestions really need more of an explanation.

Comment: Are you able to modify these types yourself? If so, you could trivially add a `Clone()` method using `Object.MemberwiseClone`. You don't really need a "deep" clone in the traditional sense, as there's nothing deep to clone... you just need a shallow clone instead of a reference.

Comment: Even if you were unable to modify the `APIRateLimit` class, you could trivially write an extension method to clone your class.